# Remove content from field in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

My `@thesis` entries in my `.bib` file have in the field `institution` information about both department and school. I'm creating a style sheet for a journal where only the name of the school (i.e. university, college, vel sim.) is needed.

As a result, I'm looking for some code that will scan the field `institution` in the `@thesis` entries and delete text from the beginning until (and including) the final instance of `.` (period + space).

If no such cases are found, as in `miller1923` below, it shouldn't do anything. If multiple cases are found, as in `anderson2008` below, it should delete all of them. In the end, only the names of the universities should remain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{miller1923,
    AUTHOR = "Oscar Miller",
    INSTITUTION = "Harvard University",
    TITLE = "War -- what is it good for?",
    TYPE = "Ph.D. dissertation",
    YEAR = "1923"}
@thesis{smith2003,
    AUTHOR = "Peter Smith",
    INSTITUTION = "Department of Chemistry. Stanford University",
    TITLE = "Oxygen and stuff",
    TYPE = "Ph.D. dissertation",
    YEAR = "2003"}
@thesis{anderson2008,
    AUTHOR = "John Anderson",
    INSTITUTION = "Department of Lang. \& Litt. Swarthmore College",
    TITLE = "Shakespeare and the English he wrote",
    TYPE = "MA thesis",
    YEAR = "2008"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using biber as a backend for biblatex in order to do things like this. Then it's quite easy. Add this to your preamble:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{thesis}
       \step[fieldsource=institution, match=\regexp{\A.+\.\s*(.+)\z}, replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

Since you mentioned that this is for a style, you should really use `\DeclareStyleSourcemap` instead of `\DeclareSourcemap` (same syntax, just replace the macro call). This can then be put in your style files.